# Vagrant ubuntu box inline scripts emitting "mesg ttyname failed Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I'm running few inline scripts at the end of each `vagrant up`.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

  ... omitting all the other steps related to networking, folders, etc

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "service nginx restart", run: "always"

  config.vm.post_up_message = "Done!"
end
```

And I get this in my logs:

```
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: mesg:
==> default: ttyname failed
==> default: :
==> default: Inappropriate ioctl for device

==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default:
==> default: Done!
```

From what I've been finding out so far - it should be something in the Ubuntu configuration, not Vagrant itself. I've found and tried this solution with no success:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7368

However, if relevant - I'm running latest Vagrant 1.8.7 and macOS Sierra.

Comment: This happens with Vagrant 1.8.7 and Ubuntu 16.04 with the shell provisioner. It has happened to me every time and you can just ignore it because the command still succeeds.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know that the command succeeds and it is triggered by the shell provisioner. But I'm asking why and how to fix it :)

Comment: Ignore it and wait for a fix from Hashicorp or Canonical.

Comment: You'll be waiting a while.  This can also be a problem for root cron jobs that leverage .profile.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it's too late for an answer on this question, but as this may help somebody else, it's good to share what I tried:

```
# Prevent TTY Errors (copied from laravel/homestead: "homestead.rb" file)... By default this is "bash -l".
config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
```

So as you can see in the commented line above - the "mesg: ttyname failed Inappropriate ioctl for device" has been prevented from the laravel team.

Most developers would like to avoid errors/warnings when we do development, so it seems like the fix we needed.

Important note: I haven't tested this solution too much, but the box starts without the "mesg: ttyname failed Inappropriate ioctl for device" error! You are free to try it and if you experience any problems, just drop a comment to save somebody else's time!

Comment: Sadly this breaks the use of commands like `vagrant ssh server -c 'command'`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it only works in VirtualBox v6.0.2 for Mojave/Catalina! (+vagrant 2.2.2 - not sure it matters though!)